# After installing Android lollipop 5.0 getting some problems

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am getting error in Eclipse after installing Android 5.0 (SDK 21)

```
Loading data for Android 5.0" has encountered a problem. 
    Parsing Data for android-21 failed
    unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I read various tutorials but didn't get good results from there, so please if anyone knows the solution, let me know. I am facing this problem after updating Sdk with 5.0(21).

Comment: Yep - the SDK devs have messed up big time and there are a lot of people having problems with the latest updates. I've been getting the major.minor version error as well and also the appcompat-v7 library project I need for my current app will no longer build. I spent 2 days trying to fix it but no luck. I've now moved to Android Studio v1.0.1 but haven't tried it with my current app project yet as I had loads of problems getting it installed and configured correctly.

Comment: Download JDK 7, and change the default JDK from 1.6 to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. Have you checked your Java version? **Android 5.0 requires Java 7**. Please check it. If you already have updated Java version to 7 and in eclipse you mentioned jre 7 then lastly check **eclipse.ini** file. Edit this file also to use Java 7.